# Fitting Survival Models in Python From Aggregate Data

Tags: r, python

I am trying to fit some basic survival models in Python.  The crux of the problem is that I have a large number of observations, so my data is binned-- ie every row is not a single subject but a count of subjects with common attributes (ie. same covariates, same time observed, same observed outcome).  It seems that the `lifelines` package requires observation-per-row to fit a Cox model. Similarly, trying to fit a Weibull curve with `scipy.stats.continuous_rv.fit` runs into the same problem.

I have done this in R without issue, as their survival regression packages all seem to accept a `weights` vector that allows for this type of data.  It seems extremely inefficient to break my aggregated data up into millions of rows when there are only 10s of thousands of unique rows in the original.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi John, Welcome to CV. Please take a tour of the [Help Section](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/135392#) to learn about what kinds of questions are on topic here. As it stands, I feel your question about fitting models in particular software is more appropriate to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `rpy2` package in Python to actually just call R.

```
importr('survival')
pandas2ri.activate()
coxph_ = r('coxph')
model = coxph_(Formula("Surv(time, outcome) ~ f1 + f2"), data=df, weights=df.num_in_group)

base = importr('base')
print(base.summary(model))
```

Not great, but gets the job done for now.  I was surprised at how *good* `rpy2` was.  It has very nice pandas <-> data.frame interoperability. The help is also quite good (rpy2.readthedocs.io).

Answer (score 0):

`lifelines`, a survival analysis library in python, now supports this functionality. To use it, just add a weight column to your dataframe of subjects and specify it in the call to `fit`.

```
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter

cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(df, duration_col="T", event_col="E", weight_col="weights")
```

Further example here: 
https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/blob/8b1249ad96833c764a8ebf78d199a104ab7cb5f5/tests/test_estimation.py#L890-L899